# if operator in vb.net giving error

Tags: vb.net

I have a line `notes = If(IsDBNull(notes),"","")` in my code . When I try running it on localhost,

I am getting the error on Line 51:

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

```
Compiler Error Message: BC30201: Expression expected.

Source Error:



Line 49:       End Try  
Line 50:       
**Line 51:     notes = If(IsDBNull(notes),"","")** 
Line 52:       'Context.Response.Output.Write("AAAA"+notes+"MMM")
Line 53:        if notes.Trim().Equals("TIMEUP") then  


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5466; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5459
```

However, when the same code is ported to production it is running without any glitch, any idea why ?

Comment: @OP: Side-note: You are assigning `String.Empty` in any case, is that desired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the [`If`-operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) was introduced with VS 2008 but you're compiling to .NET Framework Version:2.0.

This will compile on .NET 2:

```
Dim notesObj As Object = IIf(IsDBNull(notes),"","")
```

The difference is that `IIF` returns an object whereas `If` is strongly typed([conditional operator (?) in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)), so you can write:

```
Dim notesStr = If(IsDBNull(notes),"","") ' a string '
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean:

```
IIf(IsDBNull(notes),"","")
```

Note the extra I.

If statements are declared as the one you see on line 53:

```
If <condition> Then
```

IIF statements are declared as:

```
IIf(Expression, True, False)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

VB.NET 2008 introduced the [`If`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb513985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) **operator**, which **short circuits** - which is to say, only ONE out of the if-true and if-false expressions is evaluated.

Prior to this, all that was available was the [`IIf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/27ydhh0d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) **function**, which, being a *function*, always evaluates *both* the if-true and if-false expressions.

It looks like your production box is using VB.NET 2008 or later, whereas your local machine is using VB.NET 2005 or earlier.